# bootstrap the right side divs are the half of the left side div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

how to do something like that with bootstrap?

[img cuz I do not know how to describe it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N1Mb.png)

Comment: What have you already tried? It's a good idea to include what you've already tried doing to overcome this, and what problems you're facing. This will make your question more focused and easier to answer concisely. Please take the [Tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap grid to achieve this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">div-1</div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">div-2</div>
      <div class="col-12">div-3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            div 1
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    div 2
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    div 3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```